# sed use wildcard and printf matched pattern

Tags: bash, sed

i`ve a sed pipe like this
`sed 's/ -/\n-/g`. But sed should only substitute -[a-z] when pattern `-[a-z]` matched and print the matched pattern. Using the above sed pipe syntax with string  `-va -10%` substitutes string to :

```
-va
-10%
```

but substition should be

`-va -10%`

using sed pipe syntax `sed 's/ -[a-z]/\n-/g` cuts the output string to  `-a -10%` but output should be  `-va -10%`. The mattched alpha letter has to be printed in output and not deleted like actual pipe does, so sed should only add linebreaks when pattern -[a-z] is matched but NOT delete strtings or letter. How can i realize this ?

regards

Comment: I think you want `sed 's/ \(-[a-z]\)/\n\1/g`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed 's/ -[a-z]/\n&/g'       # if leading whitespace doesn't bother you
sed -E 's/ (-[a-z])/\n\1/g' # if leading whitespace does matter
sed 's/ \(-[a-z]\)/\n\1/g'  # Same as last one, but without extended regexp flag, making us have to escape the capture-group paranthesis
```